# un / re-installing Office365 language pack

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, office365, language-pack

I was on Office 2010 and got asked to be in the pilot group for Office 365. After this period O365 went live and I deemed it a good idea to uninstall Office 2010.

After this was done all Office related filetypes lost their association with office and excel woorkbooks were always opened as a blank file.

Since repairing the installation did not resolve the issue I tried uninstalling. Since Office 365 is installed as 10 different products (1 for each language) on my machine I have to uninstall one by one.

After I uninstalled to de-DE version, which is my native locale, everyting worked again in en-US. Here comes my problem: How can I re-install the German language pack  or uninstall Office 365 in a one-click manner completly to get it re-installed from the system center from scratch?

I can't just go to the System center configruation manager and click install. The system then will tell me, that office is already installed. If I uninstall everything by hand, I have to calculate about 2 hours per language pack at current performance of my hard drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to uninstall every Office365 language pack at once. What you will need is the setup files of offices, namely `setup.exe`.

- First of all, create a .cmd file with the following commands:

  "%~dp0setup.exe" /configure "%~dp0removeOffice.xml"

As a second step create an xml file and fill it with the following script:

```
 <Configuration>
      <Remove OfficeClientEdition="32" >
        <Product ID="O365ProPlusRetail">
          <Language ID="en-us" />
          <Language ID="nl-nl" />
          <Language ID="fr-fr" />
          <Language ID="de-de" />
          <Language ID="it-it" />
          <Language ID="es-es" />
          <Language ID="pl-pl" />
          <Language ID="cs-cz" />
          <Language ID="ro-ro" />
          <Language ID="sk-sk" />
        </Product>
      </Remove>  
      <Updates Enabled="TRUE" />
      <Display Level="full" AcceptEULA="TRUE" />
      <Logging Name="OfficeSetup.txt" Path="%temp%" />
    </Configuration>
```

Fill in every language pack which is installed on your computer.

- Execute the .cmd file
- Reboot

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate you going to the trouble of adding this, but sadly I'm unsure on some of the steps. I've not created a .cmd file before and am unsure where to enter %~dp0setup.exe configure %~dp0removeOffice.xml.

Are you able to add some more detailed steps?

Cheers

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1158112)