# uninstall a non-win32 software silently using PowerShell

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, uninstall

My company installs a bunch of unnecessary software on my operating system which I really don't like and they cause quite some trouble for me. consider the software `foobar` that shows up in the list of installed software in `Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features`. However it does not show up when I search with:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product
```

command. So I can not use [this solution](https://superuser.com/a/1485620/588662). When I use the

```
Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
```

I can see the program.

I just want to uninstall this software silently every time I boot my operating system. I have admin rights on my computer so that should not be a problem. I am using Windows 10 22H2.

**P.S.1.** Doing some research I tried the following cmd command and it works.

```
"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ClickToRun\OfficeClickToRun.exe" scenario=install scenariosubtype=uninstall sourcetype=None productstoremove=O365ProPlusRetail.16_de-de_x-none culture=de-de version.16=16.0 DisplayLevel=False forceappshutdown=true
```

**P.S.2.** I wonder if I can below command

```
msiexec.exe /x {<packageRegisteryName>} /qn
```

Comment: 32-bit software will be under `WOW6442Node` like `Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\Software\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"`. Checking both places lists most installed software with some exceptions like windows store apps

Comment: @Cpt.Whale I am not sure if I get your point. May you be kind to elaborate on how your comment can help me solve my problem?

Comment: "My company installs a bunch of unnecessary software on my operating system..." Have you checked with IT staff if you are **allowed** to remove it? A corporate PC may have time-tracking and other apps they require (though admittedly, likely not the *foobar* audio app).

Comment: @DrMoishePippik yes I am allowed to remove it because I am an admin on my machine and those software are just Dutch and German versions of Office 365.

Comment: Otherwise, I believe the answer you need is something like this answer as I do have rep in uninstalling Office 365 and use the XML with applicable parameters defined and run the setup.exe pointing to that XML and it just works. I suspect if you did the same for your language pack removes, you could then just run the setup.exe passing in the applicable XML as a parameters that has the necessary values and parameters defined in the XML to remove those language packs: https://superuser.com/questions/865466/un-re-installing-office365-language-pack @Foad

Comment: @Foad - You can't have multiple versions of Office 365 installed.  So, are you trying to uninstall language packs for Office 365?  If so, you are better off doing so through Office.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this PowerShell fragment :

```
$program = Get-ChildItem -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall, HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall | Get-ItemProperty | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -match "Part of App Name" } | Select-Object -Property DisplayName, Uninstallstring, QuietUninstallString 

start-process cmd.exe -argumentlist "/c ""$($prog.quietUninstallString) /norestart""" -Wait
```

Where "Part of App Name" is enough to uniquely identify the
product.

Comment: (Note that I haven't actually tested this code.)

Comment: I tried this command. I don't think that it works. please check my **P.S.** maybe it helps.

Comment: Your command is the uninstall command specific for Office. I tried the command in my answer and it works. The problem might be that your product doesn't have a `QuietUninstallString` and only has `UninstallString`. This is easy to verify by, after executing the assignment `$program = ...` to execute the simple command `$program` which will display the contents of the variable.

Comment: I believe that my product indeed doesn't have a `QuietUninstallString`.

Comment: You would need for these products to use the `UninstallString` string.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to write a small PowerShell script for my specific need:

```
# Name of the software to check
$softwareName = "O365ProPlusRetail - de-de"

# Check if software is installed
$software = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Where-Object { $_.PSChildName -match $softwareName }

if ($software -ne $null) {
    # Software is installed, uninstall it
    & 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ClickToRun\OfficeClickToRun.exe' scenario=install scenariosubtype=uninstall sourcetype=None productstoremove=O365ProPlusRetail.16_de-de_x-none culture=de-de version.16=16.0 DisplayLevel=False forceappshutdown=true
    Write-Host "$softwareName has been uninstalled."
}
else {
    # Software is not installed
    Write-Host "$softwareName is not installed."
}
```

it works for me but this is not a general solution.